# Run-time error while creating a ListView

Tags: java, android, listview

I am facing this error while creating a ListView.

---

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

---

### MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    ListView l;
    String[] names = {"aaa","bbb","ccc"};


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        l = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        ArrayAdapter ad = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.activity_list_item,names);
        l.setAdapter(ad);

    }
}
```

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'

Comment: can you post full logcat?

Answer (score 1):

just comment out this section of your code:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

and then replace :

```
l = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_view);
ArrayAdapter ad = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.activity_list_item,names);
l.setAdapter(ad);
```

with:

```
​setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,​​​​​​​​​​​​android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, names));
```

or you can keep your code and just change ListActivity to Activity

Comment: I did but now getting this error:- Error:(26, 9) error: illegal character: '\u200b'

Comment: @mt00100 i dont think it(new error) has something to do with your question in first place, try to give more detail of your code and your logcat

Comment: @mt00100 or you can keep your code and just change ListActivity to Activity